# reveal.js: How to write Mathjax formulas inline?

Tags: mathjax, reveal.js

So far, every math formula I've written using MathJax in reveal.js puts it on a line of its own. I want to be able to write them on the same line as say, text in a `<p>` tag, and control line breaks for the formulae.

The MathJax dependency specified in the `dependencies` array of the object passed to the `Reveal.initialize` call is:

```
{ src: '/plugin/math/math.js', async: true }
```

Which is the same as that shown at the reveal.js github documentation. In other words, I did not configure MathJax in any other way.

Thanks!

Comment: Make sure you are using in0line math delimiters `$...$` or `\(...\)` not display math delimiters `$$...$$` or `\[...\]`.

Comment: Hey Davide, thanks a lot, it works. Do you want to add your comment as an answer?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Make sure you use the in-line math delimiters `$...$` or `\(...\)` not display math delimiters `$$...$$` or `\[...\]` which (among other things) cause the math to be displayed on a separate line.